# How to sign in to vs code accounts management and how does it works?

Tags: authentication, github, visual-studio-code

I have updated my vs code to 1.46.0 yesterday, and I have discovered this feature :
[VS Code account icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5uJI.png)

I have searched in the [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46) of the upgrade, and I searched in vs code commands :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgQ7Y.png)

But I still can't find yet how to sign in to github for example. Is it in vs code insiders
or did I not search well ?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

Comment: @rioV8 sorry, but this is only available on vs code insiders (written in the note at the starting of the page), I am on the stable version of VS Code on Kubuntu

Comment: I also got confused by this icon. Seems like it was included in stable release by mistake. Downvoters, why?

Comment: @disfated I don't really know for the downvoters. But yes, It's bizarre about the icon. I don't find answer yet in any doc (of stable version).

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone the private repo from command pallet, it will ask to sign-in into GitHub, that's what is shown in my account section of vscode.

Comment: I tried, but it does not work since I log into my terminal. I don't know how I manage to deactivate it but I don't have the sign-in input interface from vs code but in my shell; maybe because I use the credential helper of git `git config credential.helper store` that vs code doesn't support ?.

Comment: I guess it might work if you did the `git clone` using command palette.